# Mount a VirtualBox drive image (vdi)?

Tags: mount, virtualbox

Is it possible to mount a VirtualBox drive image (.vdi) so the contents can be viewed in Nautilus etc.?

I have a windows 2000 .vdi which won't boot ("inaccessible boot device") after upgrading from VirtualBox 2.x to 3.1.6. I believe the IDE drive details have changed and that all I need to do is access the internal drive image and edit the Windows `boot.ini` to point to the new location.

Comment: If your .vdi and then .img file contains more then 1 partition, this is very useful:
[browse-img-without-mounting](http://askubuntu.com/questions/236263/browse-img-without-mounting)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can convert into standard image and then mount it.

```
VBoxManage clonehd --format RAW ubuntu.vdi ubuntu.img
```

Then

```
mount -t ext3 -o loop,rw ./ubuntu.img /mnt
```

You will need to KNOW the type of file system, `ext3` in this case. After it is mounted, go in and edit away with the editor of your choice. Don't confuse files inside the `/mnt` location with the running host, or it will be bad.

To check details about your VDI file, run: `VBoxManage showhdinfo ubuntu.vdi`.

Source: [[SOLVED] Open .vdi with archive manager? - ubuntuforums.org](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1511162)

Comment: Specilly useful in a situation like this. OP will be able to work on the copy keeping the original as backup.

Comment: Careful doing this with dynamically sized .vdi files. Converting to .img will force the image file to be as big as the logical size of the disk, which is why this approach works, but it might be much larger than .vdi file was. Take a look at the output of `VBoxManage showhdinfo [your vdi file]` if you're not sure.

Comment: -1, [stwissel](http://askubuntu.com/a/132999/7264) and [Maxime R.](http://askubuntu.com/a/50290/7264)'s answers provide solutions--this is a fair workaround, but not the best answer to the question

Comment: If the image has a partition table (like most drives), then you will need to combine this answer with [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419489/loopback-mounting-individual-partitions-from-within-a-file-that-contains-a-parti#9153530) to mount the individual partitions.

Comment: Doesn't work. Keep getting mounting errors wrong fs type. I tried ext3 and ext2 and ext4 . Virtual  box says the hd fs type is ext4 .

Comment: Since you cloned the vdi as RAW maybe it needs mount -t raw ?

Comment: You can put the image on loop: `losetup -P /dev/loopX ubuntu.img` (where X is index of the first unused loop device) then `mount /dev/loopXpY /mnt` (where Y is the index of the partition you want to mount).

Comment: Converting the whole image is very ineffective. Also this solution does not let you edit the disk file.

Answer (score 152):

Use `qemu-nbd`, the process is explained [on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/210684/how-do-you-mount-a-vdi-image-on-linux/210685#210685) and [in this blog](http://bethesignal.org/blog/2011/01/05/how-to-mount-virtualbox-vdi-image/).

Basically, you'll have to install `qemu` if needed:

```
sudo apt-get install qemu qemu-utils
```

Then you'll need to load the *network block device* module:

```
sudo rmmod nbd
sudo modprobe nbd max_part=16
```

Attach the .vdi image to one of the nbd you just created:

```
sudo qemu-nbd -c /dev/nbd0 drive.vdi
```

Now you will get a /dev/nbd0 block device, along with several /dev/nbd0p* partition device nodes.

```
sudo mount /dev/nbd0p1 /mnt
```

Once you are done, unmount everything and disconnect the device:

```
sudo qemu-nbd -d /dev/nbd0
```

Comment: I'd like to note that `max_part=16` seems to be a critical part. Without it you won't see any `/dev/nbd0pX` files, despite the main device will work properly. Check the following discussion on [Gentoo forums](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-822672-start-0.html) to see people met this trouble.

Comment: All answers work to some extent but this is my favorite and should be the accepted one. clonehd do the job but doubles storage requirements. virtualbox-fuse is ideal but although you can still get it, it didn't make it to the repos in modern releases of OS.

Comment: Wonderful! This is absolutely the best method to use a .vdi file! I was getting dumb errors cloning or resizing the VDI, but this method bypasses all problems :)

`VBoxManage: error: Could not create the clone medium '/mnt/temp6/xubuntu-14.04-64bit.img'.
VBoxManage: error: Raw: disk would overflow creating image '/mnt/temp6/xubuntu-14.04-64bit.img' (VERR_DISK_FULL)
`
`VBOX_E_NOT_SUPPORTED
VBoxManage: error: Resize hard disk operation for this format is not implemented yet!`

Comment: Also think this is the better answer. I for one was not very keen on cloning my 100 GB image just to get to a couple of files ;) Mounting via `qemu-nbd ` worked like a charm.

Comment: This worked great. Note that installing `qemu-kvm` instead of `qemu` may work just as well. It did for me on my Ububtu 16.04, and installed only 23MB and 13 dependencies instead of 230MB and many more dependencies for the full qemu install.

Comment: please note that it worked for me only: sudo qemu-nbd -c /dev/nbd1 drive.vdi for a reason, otherwise i had error: mount: special device /dev/nbd0p1 does not exist

Comment: On Debian buster amd64 I installed only ~qemu-utils~ and its dependencies, for a total of just a few MB of disk usage, and it worked: I successfully mounted the .vdi and copied one file.

Comment: I'd like to add that apparently `sudo partprobe` needs to be executed with newer kernels so that `/dev/nbd0p*` are created in Debian/Ubuntu (https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=824553).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!! My vdi is too big to convert to an .iso on my hard drive. After struggling for a while, I scrolled down to see if any other methods used the vdi directly. This one is simple. (Note: qemu takes about 300MB for those of us who care about our hard drive filling up.)

Comment: If `nbd0p1` doesn't appear, run `sudo kpartx -av /dev/nbd0`, it will add it to `/dev/mapper/`

Comment: Note that in Debian `qemu-nbd` is in `qemu-kvm` package, so you should install with `apt-get install qemu-kvm`.

Comment: Just to note that this worked for me on 19.10 with no partprobe required.

Comment: Great job, works like a charm!

Comment: Problem with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I got `sudo: qemu-nbd: command not found`

Comment: Everything worked fine for me except that the mounted drive didn't show any contents... however, binwalk finds a lot of files in the VDI file. I tried the first anser as well, and again only got an empty directory on my mountpoint. Not sure why.

Comment: in order to solve the `sudo: qemu-nbd: command not found` on ubuntu you need to install an additional package `sudo apt-get install qemu-utils`

Comment: The links at beginning of this answer are dead

Comment: Is this solution safe for snapshots?

Answer (score 40):

It looks like [vdfuse](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/vdfuse.1.html) is the tool you are looking for. It is in the Ubuntu repositories. If you want to compile yourself (2010 source) you can [do that too](http://robsworldoftech.blogspot.com/2010/11/mounting-any-virtualbox-supported-vdi.html).

However for most of us it boils down to a simple:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-fuse
```

It seems it now supports dynamic vdi as well.

And to mount the `.vdi` file in `/mnt` dir use the command:

```
sudo vdfuse -a -f /path-to-vdi-file /mnt
```

The entire disk will be mounted with partitions `Partition1` , `Partition2` naming format. Then those files can be loop mounted. For example,

```
sudo mount -o loop /mnt/Parition1 /mountpoint
```

Comment: Thanks for pitching in. vdfuse has already been provided as an answer though. Please improve that answer instead of adding a duplicate.

Comment: @mattwilkie: The difference now: no manual compile required anymore

Comment: ok, with that edit this answer is now better than the previous 1 liner.

Comment: You are welcome. Sitting at a propper screen/keyboard instead of pecking on glas made all the difference :-)

Comment: Advantage of vdfuse is that it does not complain about disk full etc. If you go with VBoxManage, you need to have additional space for mounting.

Comment: It's not available in 14.04.

Comment: One can download it from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/vdfuse/?source=typ_redirect and it works (on 15.04)

Comment: `vdfuse` from the link above (at sourceforge) isn't working on 16.04.

Comment: No longer valid for 16.10, package no longer exists.

Answer (score 16):

Set the disk as secondary master for another virtual OS, then boot into this (virtual) OS and you can mount it.

**Step 1:** Assuming you have a virtual os(say Ubuntu 16.04) already installed in Virtual box, add a new storage from settings of that virtual os.
[image]

**Step 2:** Browse the Vdi file you want to access and select it.

**Step 3:** Logon to the virtual OS.

**Step 4:** The virtual disk will probably be available inside the OS. If not, follow step 5

**Step 5:** Inside the virtual OS, use Gparted and check the disks. and ensure the disk is of type which is accessible by the virtual OS. If it is not, you may have to edit the disk, but then you will lose the existing contents.

Comment: For the record, in 2016 it won't work

Comment: It works in ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: this is really the only solution when you need to make changes and then go back to using it, couldn't get rw working with vdfuse

Comment: you can even use a live ubuntu and add the .vdi file as extra strorage.

Answer (score 9):

> **Moderator Notice:** The `vdfuse` module and packages have been obsolete since 2016 as they were removed from the Ubuntu repositories.  While this answer is now obsolete, due to the age of the post and the fact it has upvotes, the answer here has been retained for historical purposes.

I haven't tested myself but there is a fuse module to mount them (`vdfuse`), check the following page:

- [HOWTO: Mount any VBox-compatible disk image on the host](http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=33355)

Please note that using it for write access is risky.

---

Usage:

```
$ ./vdfuse-v<version> -h
USAGE: ./vdfuse [options] -f image-file mountpoint
   -h   help
   -r   readonly
   -t   specify type (VDI, VMDK, VHD, or raw; default: auto)
   -f   VDimage file
   -a   allow all users to read disk
   -w   allow all users to read and write to disk
   -g   run in foreground
   -v   verbose
   -d   debug
```

To mount an image directly using its filename:

```
$ ./vdfuse-v<version> -f image.vdi /mnt/vdi
$ mount -o loop /mnt/vdi/Partition1 /mnt/WindowsXP
```

To mount an machine disk (including snapshots):

```
$ ./vdautomount-<version> -p /path/to/vdfuse WinXP /mnt/vdi
$ mount -o loop /mnt/vdi/Partition1 /mnt/WindowsXP
```

Comment: No longer relevant as this utility isn't supported.

Answer (score 9):

Make `VirtualBox` disk images available to the host by using [vboximg-mount](https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/user/vboximg-mount.html) utility:

##### Open VDI

```
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/vdi/expanded
sudo vboximg-mount -i <path-to-vdi> -o allow_other /mnt/vdi/expanded
```

###### Output Example

```
ls /mnt/vdi/expanded
<filename.vdi>  vhdd  vol0  vol1
```

##### Mount Disk

```
mkdir /mnt/vdi/vol1
sudo mount /mnt/vdi/expanded/vol1 /mnt/vdi/vol1
```

##### Unmount

```
cd /mnt                       # Optional (avoid mount: ... target is busy)
sudo umount /mnt/vdi/vol1     # Order importent
sudo umount /mnt/vdi/expanded
rm -rf /mnt/vdi               # Optional (clean-up resources)
```

Comment: Alternatively (to `vboximg-mount -i <path-to-vdi>`), list all of the user VDIs with `vboximg-mount --list --wide` and specify their UUID to `vboximg-mount` (i.e. `vboximg-mount -i <UUID> [...]`).

Comment: I found `-i <UUID>` only worked when not using `sudo`. Without `sudo` the second mount for the partition failed. With `sudo`, I needed to use a full path to the `.vdi` image with the `-i` option.

Comment: I tried to mount a `vdi` image locally with FreeDOS 1.3 RC4: same output but I had to mount `vol0` and not vol1 specifying `-t vfat` and the full path because the relative one didn't work...

Answer (score 8):

You can use `vboximg-mount` program which is a part of the VirtualBox's command line tools.

Comment: Interesting! It  crashed with a segmentation fault for me, but this is the first answer that mentions this tool, so I upvoted.

Answer (score 7):

As Vojtech Trefny mentioned above,

1) first convert your VDI -> IMG

```
VBoxManage clonehd --format RAW ubuntu.vdi ubuntu.img
```

2) Then mount the IMG

```
mount -t ext3 -o loop,rw ./ubuntu.img /mnt
```

3) However, as I got this error message:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

and dmesg said:

```
[3105578.013671] EXT4-fs (loop0): VFS: Can't find ext3 filesystem
```

you need to check out the partition structure of the .img:

```
fdisk -l ubuntu.img

Disk ubuntu.img: 21.0 GB, 20971520000 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 2549 cylinders, total 40960000 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xf45bc910

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
ubuntu.img1   *        2048    12582911     6290432   83  Linux
ubuntu.img2        12584958    16775167     2095105    5  Extended
ubuntu.img3        16775168    40959999    12092416   83  Linux
ubuntu.img5        12584960    16775167     2095104   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

4) As you can see, the main partition is starting at bytes 16775168. However, note that the sector size is 512 bytes, so you need to multiply the results 16775168 x 512 = 8588886016 so you need to offset the mount like this:

```
mount -t ext3 -o loop,rw,offset=8588886016 ./ubuntu.img /mnt
```

5) Actually this didn't work for me in case where the filesystem was dirty after resize. In this case I further did this:

```
dd if=ubuntu.img of=ubuntu.disk bs=512 skip=16775168 count=12092416
e2fsck ubuntu.disk
mount ubuntu.disk /mnt
```

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question. You had another problem -- a corrupt image. You should have self-answered a new question.

Comment: This expands to the previous answer covering the error case. Corrupt image was one use case. +1 for many new tricks.

Answer (score 3):

Not what you requested, but if it's just a matter of **getting files off of the vdi**, and you want **a very quick solution**:

1. Run an ssh server on your host (`apt-get install openssh-server && service ssh restart`)
2. Use VirtualBox to build a virtual machine from the existing vdi file, then boot up that virtual machine. (I just kept the default Network Adapter (NAT) when building the VM.)
3. Within the virtual machine, sftp to your host. (`sftp hostuser@hostip`)
4. In the sftp session, `put` as many files to the host as you need.

Comment: An ugly hack, but if you're in a tight spot, it gets the job done.

Comment: One problem may be that the machine doesn't currently boot correctly so you'd need to fix that problem first and that means you can't do it from within. Also using SSH with your virtualbox OSes is the way to go to copy files around. Way faster than trying to share a disk.

Comment: The guest system needs to have SSH installed for this to work. Easy on a Linux guest, less straightforward on a Windows guest.

Answer (score 3):

### P7Zip will open VDI files

- Install **P7Zip - Desktop** from Ubuntu Software from [this link](https://snapcraft.io/p7zip-desktop) or by running:

  ```
  sudo snap install p7zip-desktop
  ```
- Launch **P7Zip Desktop** and navigate to the folder containing the `.vdi` file (probably under `VirtualBox VMs` in your home directory)
- Double click the VDI file in the P7Zip window.
- View or extract files as you like.

Comment: This seems to load the oldest snapshot, rather than the current  state of the guest filesystem.

Comment: P7zip is the simplest approach if we just need to extract a single file from a valid VDI. However, it seems bugged, becase it can open VDIs only in the current file system, while it doesn't open files in other mounted file system in `/media`.

Answer (score 1):

The `qemu` approach from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19430/mount-a-virtualbox-drive-image-vdi/50290#50290) needed to be modified a bit to work in Ubuntu 20.04.1. First I had to load the `nbd` module, by:

```
lsmod | grep nbd
modprobe nbd
```

This did not work:

```
sudo mount /dev/nbd0p1 /mnt
```

I needed to do this instead:

```
sudo mount /dev/nbd0p2 /mnt
```

Comment: What does `sudo fdisk -l /dev/nbd0` show? After the `modprobe` command, you need to run `sudo qemu-nbd --connect=/dev/nbd0 /path/to/your/image-file`.