# How can I mount a VirtualBox harddisk?

Tags: mount, virtualbox, virtualization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mount a Virtual Box drive image (vdi)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19430/mount-a-virtual-box-drive-image-vdi)

I have a VirtualBox harddisk, let's say here:

```
~/harddisk/ubuntu.vdi
```

How can I mount it using FUSE, so that it's accessible from the host PC?

Please assume that I've almost no knowledge about FUSE and mounting.

Comment: A bit of googling and I found this (no idea how useful it is) http://www.mat.uniroma1.it/~caminati/mount_vdi.html

Comment: Similar post [here](http://superuser.com/questions/34913/mount-virtualbox-vdi-disk)

Comment: +1 Good question. Those two links above suggest it is only possible if you set up your virtual disc as "fixed size" rather than "variable size"

Comment: reading may be successful to some point but writing to a variable sized VDI will destroy it.

Comment: Reading would be just fine.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I would use [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/)  to backup the partition to a file and then restore the partition into your other vm.    I'm not familiar with FUSE but I am guessing that this is the general idea of what you need to do.

Comment: I actually just wanted to access them in order to have a bridge to my virtual system.