# access specific folder on Ubuntu VirtualBox from Windows host

Tags: directory, sharing, smb

Need to access /etc folder which resides on Ubuntu guest (VirtualBox) from Windows 7 host. VM working on NAT, Guest Additions Installed along with SMB. Any ideas, gentlemen's? Shared Folders Option in VirtualBox seems useless in this case, huh?

Answer (score 0):

don't know if [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19430/mount-a-virtualbox-drive-image-vdi) could help you (I haven't understood how you want to access /etc if from windows host or from where).
Obviously, if you need access to /etc while guestOS is running, this won't be the right way.

Cheers,

Silvia