# How to convert vmdk to bootable Disk or usb

Tags: boot, virtualbox, mac, vmdk

I have `Mac os 10.12` in `vmdk` format and used it by `VirtualBox` on ubuntu.

How to can i convert this `vmdk` file to bootable Disk or Usb for installing mac os?

Comment: To use to setup a new install in a pc?

Comment: @George Yes, To use to setup a new install in a pc

Comment: Is it a turnkey version of linux?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @George ubuntu 15.10

Answer (score 0):

these steps:

1. Convert the `vmdk` file to `vhd` (use a tool to do so)
2. Flash the `vhd` file to your USB devices.

then you may know..

Comment: Could you provide more detailed instructions. Right now, this is more of a comment than a complete answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create an installer out of an installed version of Mac OS, nor would a question about such specifics about Mac OS be on topic here. What you can do is to convert the virtual disk image to a raw disk image, to write it to a hard disk which should boot. You can do this with VirtualBox via `vboxmanage clonemedium disk input_file --format RAW output_file`. Tools like gnome-disks provide an easy way to write such raw images to hard disks, just rename the file extension to .img and click restore image, or use dd on the command line. Beware that you destroy all data that was on the drive selected as the target for the raw image.

Here is a very similar question on Unix SE: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/18775/49853

And another answer that is very similar considering the commands used:
https://askubuntu.com/a/19431/40581