# How to mount vmdk to SDcard partition lubuntu 18.4

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, virtualbox, lubuntu

I've seen [Mount vmdk disk ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043115/mount-vmdk-disk-ubuntu) and [How to mount a virtual hard disk?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202571/how-to-mount-a-virtual-hard-disk) as well as [How to convert vmdk to bootable Disk or usb](https://askubuntu.com/questions/895152/how-to-convert-vmdk-to-bootable-disk-or-usb) but I'm still having some problems.

I had a 32GB sd card.  I went, in lubuntu, to system-tools gparted and made a partition of 2GB, under Linux File system. Here's my output for sudo fdisk -l:

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 1 GiB, 1115181056 bytes, 2178088 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 774.1 MiB, 811728896 bytes, 1585408 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes




Disk /dev/sda: 3.8 GiB, 4022337024 bytes, 7856127 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x59fdf6ce

Device     Boot   Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         38 7839719 7839682  3.8G  b W95 FAT32
/dev/sda2       7839744 7854079   14336    7M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT


Disk /dev/sdb: 29.7 GiB, 31914983424 bytes, 62333952 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x7d0ee0dd

Device     Boot    Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1           2048 58241023 58238976 27.8G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sdb2       58241024 62332927  4091904    2G 83 Linux


Disk /dev/zram0: 470 MiB, 492838912 bytes, 120322 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/zram1: 470 MiB, 492838912 bytes, 120322 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/zram2: 470 MiB, 492838912 bytes, 120322 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/zram3: 470 MiB, 492838912 bytes, 120322 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

And here is my system info (just to be complete):

```
sudo lshw -short
H/W path                   Device      Class          Description
=================================================================
                                       system         Inspiron N5040 (To be fill
/0                                     bus            0R08PM
/0/4                                   processor      Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPU  
/0/4/5                                 memory         64KiB L1 cache
/0/4/6                                 memory         512KiB L2 cache
/0/4/7                                 memory         3MiB L3 cache
/0/4/1.1                               processor      Logical CPU
/0/4/1.2                               processor      Logical CPU
/0/4/1.3                               processor      Logical CPU
/0/4/1.4                               processor      Logical CPU
/0/4/1.5                               processor      Logical CPU
/0/4/1.6                               processor      Logical CPU
/0/4/1.7                               processor      Logical CPU
/0/4/1.8                               processor      Logical CPU
/0/4/1.9                               processor      Logical CPU
/0/4/1.a                               processor      Logical CPU
/0/4/1.b                               processor      Logical CPU
/0/4/1.c                               processor      Logical CPU
/0/4/1.d                               processor      Logical CPU
/0/4/1.e                               processor      Logical CPU
/0/4/1.f                               processor      Logical CPU
/0/4/1.10                              processor      Logical CPU
/0/14                                  memory         4GiB System Memory
/0/14/0                                memory         4GiB DIMM DDR3 Synchronous
/0/14/1                                memory         DIMM [empty]
/0/0                                   memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/1                                   processor      
/0/1/1.1                               processor      Logical CPU
/0/1/1.2                               processor      Logical CPU
/0/1/1.3                               processor      Logical CPU
/0/1/1.4                               processor      Logical CPU
/0/1/1.5                               processor      Logical CPU
/0/1/1.6                               processor      Logical CPU
/0/1/1.7                               processor      Logical CPU
/0/1/1.8                               processor      Logical CPU
/0/1/1.9                               processor      Logical CPU
/0/1/1.a                               processor      Logical CPU
/0/1/1.b                               processor      Logical CPU
/0/1/1.c                               processor      Logical CPU
/0/1/1.d                               processor      Logical CPU
/0/1/1.e                               processor      Logical CPU
/0/1/1.f                               processor      Logical CPU
/0/1/1.10                              processor      Logical CPU
/0/100                                 bridge         Core Processor DRAM Contro
/0/100/2                               display        Core Processor Integrated 
/0/100/16                              communication  5 Series/3400 Series Chips
/0/100/1a                              bus            5 Series/3400 Series Chips
/0/100/1a/1                usb1        bus            EHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1a/1/1                          bus            Integrated Rate Matching H
/0/100/1a/1/1/3            scsi7       storage        USB2.0-CRW
/0/100/1a/1/1/3/0.0.0      /dev/sdb    disk           31GB Multi-Card
/0/100/1a/1/1/3/0.0.0/0    /dev/sdb    disk           31GB 
/0/100/1a/1/1/3/0.0.0/0/1  /dev/sdb1   volume         27GiB Windows FAT volume
/0/100/1a/1/1/3/0.0.0/0/2  /dev/sdb2   volume         1998MiB EXT4 volume
/0/100/1a/1/1/4                        multimedia     Integrated Webcam
/0/100/1b                              multimedia     5 Series/3400 Series Chips
/0/100/1c                              bridge         5 Series/3400 Series Chips
/0/100/1c.1                            bridge         5 Series/3400 Series Chips
/0/100/1c.1/0              wlp18s0b1   network        BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless
/0/100/1c.2                            bridge         5 Series/3400 Series Chips
/0/100/1c.2/0              enp19s0     network        RTL810xE PCI Express Fast 
/0/100/1c.4                            bridge         5 Series/3400 Series Chips
/0/100/1d                              bus            5 Series/3400 Series Chips
/0/100/1d/1                usb2        bus            EHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1d/1/1                          bus            Integrated Rate Matching H
/0/100/1d/1/1/4            scsi6       storage        SanDisk Cruzer
/0/100/1d/1/1/4/0.0.0      /dev/sda    disk           4022MB SanDisk Cruzer
/0/100/1d/1/1/4/0.0.0/0    /dev/sda    disk           4022MB 
/0/100/1d/1/1/4/0.0.0/0/1  /dev/sda1   volume         3827MiB Windows FAT volume
/0/100/1d/1/1/4/0.0.0/0/2  /dev/sda2   volume         15EiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/100/1e                              bridge         82801 Mobile PCI Bridge
/0/100/1f                              bridge         HM57 Chipset LPC Interface
/0/100/1f.2                            storage        5 Series/3400 Series Chips
/0/100/1f.3                            bus            5 Series/3400 Series Chips
/0/100/1f.6                            generic        5 Series/3400 Series Chips
/0/101                                 bridge         Core Processor QuickPath A
/0/102                                 bridge         Core Processor QuickPath A
/0/103                                 bridge         Core Processor QPI Link 0
/0/104                                 bridge         1st Generation Core i3/5/7
/0/105                                 bridge         1st Generation Core i3/5/7
/0/106                                 bridge         1st Generation Core i3/5/7
/0/2                       scsi1       storage        
/0/2/0.0.0                 /dev/cdrom  disk           DVD+-RW DS-8A8SH
/1                                     power          DELL W7H3N06
```

And CPU info:

```
sudo lscpu
Architecture:        i686
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              4
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-3
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  2
Socket(s):           1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               37
Model name:          Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPU       M 390  @ 2.67GHz
Stepping:            5
CPU MHz:             1642.128
CPU max MHz:         2660.0000
CPU min MHz:         931.0000
BogoMIPS:            5319.85
Virtualization:      VT-x
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            256K
L3 cache:            3072K
```

Basically I'm trying to mount a vsdk [android x86](https://www.osboxes.org/android-x86/) file ([originally downlaoded as a .vdi](https://sourceforge.net/projects/osboxes/files/v/vb/1-A-d/4.4/r1/r1.7z/download) and converted with virtualbox)

I saw [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49000377) that suggested using the following commands:

```
sudo modprobe nbd
sudo qemu-nbd -r -c /dev/nbd1 ./linux_box/VM/image.vmdk
mount /dev/nbd1p1 /mnt
```

However when I run the second one (`sudo qemu-nbd -r -c /dev/nbd2 ./ok.vmdk`, after running `sudo apt-get install update` and `sudo apt-getinstall qemu-utils`), followed by `sudo mount /dev/nbd2 /mnt`, I get:

```
mount: /mnt: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/nbd2, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I set the partition earlier as ext4 (you can see it in the first output), I don't know what other file system to put?