# How to recover deleted files which are on windows virtual machine on VirtualBox?

Tags: windows, virtualbox, data-recovery

I have a Windows 10 virtual machine in VirtualBox on Ubuntu host.

I have accidentally deleted some files on virtual machine, and I need to recover them.

I have used ntfsundelete before but I think I can't use that now because my Windows partition is in .vdi file, not on a device.

So is there a way I recover those files?

Comment: Yeah, but I'll be recovering it using Linux programs.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/425518/recover-files-from-a-broken-virtualbox-machine-vdi

Comment: Also please look at [https://askubuntu.com/questions/19430/mount-a-virtualbox-drive-image-vdi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19430/mount-a-virtualbox-drive-image-vdi)

Comment: Relevant: https://askubuntu.com/a/776317/271

Comment: Anyways, the solution is simply: boot an Ubuntu live ISO inside the VM and use the instructions provided in many similar questions on how to restore deleted files from NTFS.

Answer (score 0):

Use the TestDisk 7 recovery, it's absolutely the best recovery I ever used. It's free as well. The interface is all in text mode, but very easy to work with. There are menus to navigate.
It has very nice dry run mode, which allows you to see what is there without affecting the storage at all.
http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

For a tutorial: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step

Comment: This may work, but I see no evidence on their website that Testdisk support the virtual disk files at a file system.

Comment: @CharlesGreen VDI can be converted to RAW using VirtualBox. Anyways there is no point in doing that as OP can boot a live Ubuntu ISO *inside* the VM.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425518/recover-files-from-a-broken-virtualbox-machine-vdi) question answered mine:

At first I didn't look into it because the question is different. I was right about that, but soon, I've found that the answer to that question answers my question much better.