# how recover files deleted in windows 10 running in virtual box?

Tags: 16.04

I am running windows 10 in Virtual Box, my OS is ubuntu 16.04.  I need to restore files deleted in the VB windows.  I have booted VB using a live ubuntu 16.04 cd and run fdisk but this only shows dev/loop.

Can someone brighter than me explain what to do to get the live cd to 'see' the windows files ?

Thanks

Comment: sorry, not entirely sure I understand. Is windows on a virtual disk? Are the deleted files just files inside the vm that god deleted? If so, this is outside the scope of askubuntu, and might be better to put on superuser (the windows stack exchange) instead

Comment: Yes, windows is on virtual disk and the files are inside the vm.  As I am trying to use an ubuntu live cd to retrieve them I thought this was the appropiate place to ask but I may try your suggestion.  Thanks

Comment: see https://askubuntu.com/questions/917434/how-to-recover-deleted-files-which-are-windows-virtual-machine-on-virtualbox

Comment: Thanks - one of the answers in this is to boot a live iso in the VM as I am trying to do but as I said my problem is fdisk doesn't come up with the windows virtual disk

Comment: Still looking for an answer if anyone has any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of free file recovery programs for Windows, you could try your luck and install one on the Windows VM.  Although if you have used the VM frequently since the deletion of said files and done things like install games or apps or moved large amounts of data there is a chance that part of the files you are looking for have been over written.  But like I said you can install or even get a portable version of recovery software to attempt to get them back.

Quick Search-

https://www.lifewire.com/free-data-recovery-software-tools-2622893

Comment: Thanks.  I have avoided using the VM, the 'overwriting' issue is why I have been trying to use a live cd rather than install recovery programs, but it's looking like I am going to end up there.

Comment: I would suggest to answer this with Linux tools as a virtual machine is more of less a file on the linux system. Windows related answers to me seem off topic.