# Is there any way to extract content of .vdi file?

Tags: windows, vdi

I am having Ubuntu as a Host machine and Windows VM. The VM is not starting. I need to take some important files from the virtual machine to Host Machine. So is there any way to extract the contents of Windows VM without running it?

Comment: Check out the answers to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/19430/1222991). There are three solid options. Hopefully one of them works for you 

Comment: @matigo: I think `VBoxManage clonehd`  has been changed to `VBoxManage clonemedium`

Answer (score 1):

### P7Zip will open VDI files

- Install **P7Zip-Desktop** from Ubuntu Software.
- Open folder containing VDI file in Nautilus, (Files).
- Right click VDI file and select `Open with Other Application`.
- Select **P7Zip Desktop**.
- Double click the VDI file in the P7Zip window.
- View or extract files as you like.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows-10, you can use [7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/) to extract vdi files.
Its an opensource and free software and very easy to use.

- Download the software
- Navigate to the your **vdi** file.
- Double click on the **vdi** file
- In my case, I saw files like **0.fat, 1.img**
- Check the file type and size to determine which file you want to open.
- Double click on the file. I double clicked on **1.img** because that was my device.
- Wait for few minutes.
- When the process is complete, you will see the complete filesystem.
- Now you can easily copy files to you windows drive.

Cheers,